# Misplaced modifier

Tags: clauses, subordinate-clauses, modifiers

Can anyone help me to rephrase with the below sentence as it is misplaced modifier

> An expert on Diptera and fossil insects, Hennig’s ideas were applicable to all
>   organisms.

Comment: Doesn't look like a misplaced modifier to me...

Comment: the word "idea" is not the "expert", hence it is misplaced modifier.

Comment: Hmm... you may have a point here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Although he was primarily] An expert on Diptera and fossil insects, Henning's ideas were applicable to all organisms [not just Diptera and insects].

The first part of this sentence is an [introductory subordinate clause](https://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/grammar_subordinate.html). The omission of the conjunction "although" is a matter of style, and may depend on the context.

---

Edit: this kind of introductory clause is called [nominative absolute](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_absolute).